# react functional component re-render one time even the state's value not change

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I'm a new fan of the React Functional Component.
When I read the document and try to do some experiments then I figure out a doubting case.

I have a custom-hook "**useAutoIncrement**" that has a **setInterval** which increases the "num" every second. The main component re-render when **this interval** fires.
Then I change setState a fixed number for custom-hook **0**. As Expected, the main component wouldn't re-render. We have been good so far :)

Then try to click "button" increment of the event handler in the main component, the main one re-render, and the custom-hook re-render also. But when the interval runs in the first next time to setState value **0**,  the strange thing happens. The main component and the custom-hook seem to re-render (I place some consolg.log and it shows up), but there is no console.log show up inside the **useEffect** both main-component and custom-hook.

[image]

Take a look at this image, 3 blue-lines. The 1st blue-line is inside the hook-effect interval function. It calls **setNum** with un-changed value. The main component shouldn't re-render but it seems did. The 2nd and 3rd blue-line print out they re-render

Can anyone explain this case to me?
**Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-ddqzc?file=/index.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
 
const useAutoIncrement = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useAutoIncrement useEffect")
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("useAutoIncrement useEffect interval")
      setNum((currentNum) => {
        return 0 // return fixed number
      })
    }, 5000)

    return () => {
      console.log("useAutoIncrement useEffect return")
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  });

  console.log("render useAutoIncrement")
  return 0
}

const CustomHook = () => {
  const initialCount = {value: 5};
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);

  const num = useAutoIncrement()
 
  const handleIncrement = () => {
    setCount((currentCount) => {
      return Object.assign({}, currentCount, {value: 2})
    });

    console.log("handleIncrement")
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("CustomHook useEffect")
    
    return () => {
      console.log("CustomHook useEffect return")
    }
  })

  console.log("CustomHook render")
 
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count.value}</h1>
 
      <button type="button" onClick={handleIncrement}>
        Increment
      </button>

      <p>Auto Increase Number: {num}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
 
export default CustomHook;
```

Comment: it's very hard to understand what exactly you mean. could you try rewording the question a little.

Comment: in short, the main component should not re-render when setState with un-changed value.
In this case, it prints console.log "render"  but not print console.log "useEffect"

Comment: no thats not how it works, it will always rerender when you fire the set state function

Comment: You are right with the Class Component. For the Functional Component, I am not sure about it. I tested with "setNum" with un-changed value, and there is no re-render fire. You could see the last line in the image I attached. That interval function always setNum(0), and there is no re-render (no console.log print out)

Comment: No, it always causes a rerender no matter if its the same or different. check the console in this example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-khhcw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Yes, I already test with the ClassComponent and it actually re-render every time I call setState and componentShouldUpdate is true. 
Could you try with the FunctionalComponent?

Comment: ... look at the actual example properly. its a functional component with a hook.

Comment: I see @JoeLloyd, when we place setNum outside the event-handler, It returns error "too many re-render". But when we but inside the event-handler, the component would not re-render. please see this demo https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-ddqzc?file=/index.js

Comment: `useAutoIncrement` is a hook not a component.  it does not "render" it runs and updates its state locally and for components reading from it

Answer (score 1):

When you clicked the button and fired the state change, your component was updated and re-rendered - you can see this from your logging above.

- `render useAutoIncrement`

  - this is the first console message your component runs into when the function fires
- `CustomHook render`

  - this is the next call in the JS stack
- `useAutoIncrement useEffect return`

  - since you are re-rendering, the previous one is being dismounted, causing this to run but react does this in a particular order so you are seeing it just before the newly called `useAutoIncrement`'s useEffect will be ran
- `CustomHook useEffect return`

  - same thing happens here in the next useEffect
- `useAutoIncrement useEffect`

  - react now runs the useEffect now that the previous one is cleaned up
- `CustomHook useEffect`

  - and this one too
- `useAutoIncrement useEffect interval`

  - interval occurs on time
- `render useAutoIncrement`

  - as discussed, setState forces update
- `CustomHook render`

  - since useAutoIncrement ran again, `num` is updated too, even tho it's the same number

Hope this helps some

Comment: I still have 2 points not clear in your explanation. First one, if the "as discussed, setState forces update" the component re-render, why the useEffect not fire (no console.log print out). The second, can you look at the last line of the image, there are 3 times print out of "useAutoIncrement useEffect interval" but no re-render console.log print out?